# JPlayer not working on IE, Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I have this site http://www.nachodelariega.com.ar/albums.php where I have uploaded a few ogg and m4a files for streaming. The code works fine on Firefox, Safari and Chrome but for some reason it doesn't work on IE, it just appears to load the song but it immediately goes back to a stop and does nothing.

I've also tested this on Opera and the songs are not playing either and on Chrome on a mac is not working too :(

My swfPath is on a folder named scripts and the relative path I used for the playlists is /scripts. I also tried using an absolute path with the same results.

Can you guys help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute links to audio files instead of relative links (it is a jPlayer Bug).

Use `m4a: "http://example.com/audio/example.m4a"`

Not `m4a: "audio/example.m4a"`

More info: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jplayer/q6hg2IDSfKE/discussion.

Answer (score 0):

looks like IE8 and below doesn't support ogg

Comment: Actually I solved it by changing my m4a files to mp3 and now it works flawlessly in all browsers, thanks!